# Dos decimales en operación matemática desde mysql en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

sólo necesito que se retorne la operación con 2 decimales en comision, ya que me retorna 6 decimales. Total esta como decimal(11,2)

```
$comisiones = DB::table('pedidos')
->select(DB::raw('SUM(total)*20/100 as comision'))
->get();
return $comisiones;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo tanto en MySQL como en PHP:

MySQL con la función TRUNCATE que acepta como segundo parámetro la cantidad de decimales:

```
->select(DB::raw('TRUNCATE(SUM(total)*20/100 as comision, 2)'))
```

O en PHP con number_format(), que funciona de forma similar :

```
number_format($comision, 2);
```

Comment: buen dato, sabía de que se podía hacer por php pero no por mysql

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias, lo logré con ROUND pero de esta manera:

```
->select(DB::raw('ROUND(SUM(total)*20/100, 2) as comision'))
```

Comment: Pero ROUND no hace exactamente lo que fue planteado en la pregunta. ROUND redondea, mientras que TRUNCATE, no.

Comment: Exacto, bien aclarado. El tema es que como el resultado es un valor de dinero (comision), me viene bien el redondeo.